# Parsing multiple rows of json in Android

Tags: android, json

I want to get a json file from my server and display it in my android app.

For now, it is ok just showing in log console.

I am able to get the whole json file, something like:

```
[{"name":"john", "surname":"connor"}, {"name":"sarah", "surname":"connor"}]
```

But, in android if I try to use a string like this, it fails because []

If I try:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result); //result has the previous string
Log.i("TEST", json.toString());
```

I have to delete [ and ] to go ahead and nn log, I just have the first entrance of my json.

If I leave [ and ], it just do nothing. Stop before the first line.

The complete example code is [here](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/%20I%20just%20changed%20the%20url).

Comment: ur original string is json Array not json Object..

Comment: @Biribu - please see http://www.json.org/ - it quite literally explains everything you need to know about JSON formatting on one page.

Comment: Thanks. I will right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace  this

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result); //result has the previous string
    Log.i("TEST", json.toString());
```

With

```
JSONArray json=new JSONArray(result); //result has the previous string
    Log.i("TEST", json.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I have all data.